# React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually, gives 404 page not found

Tags: reactjs, react-router

My production webiste opens normally, but for a user visiting/accessing that link the first time, he gets a `404 Page Not Found`. For users that has already visited the website it loads just fine.

This is the url - https://literacycloud.org/readaloudsdetail/546-jennifer-phillips-reads-the-invitation.

Ideally it should redirect to the login page, but there is no api being hit at all.
The issue doesn't get reproduced locally only when deployed to development or to live, getting this issue.

Is it something back-end has to handle from their end?

Any help appreciated.

[image: The below image show the error when a new user enters the url]

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: Probably I had the same issue recently, it happens because you should return index.html for any request from your back-end

Answer (score 0):

Set `historyApiFallback` in your `webpack.config.js`. Checkout [this](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverhistoryapifallback).

Also, it is a good idea to serve your `index.html` from a server. The idea is that no matter what url you visit on your domain, the server should always return the `index.html` as it contains your react code.

Here is a sample code:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.get("*", (req, res, next) => {
    const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html');

    res.sendFile(filePath);
});

const server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('listening on port ', server.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Have this set-up in my webpack.config.js currently. 
historyApiFallback: { disableDotRule: true }. 
Is it Enough ?